# How to use Vuejs SFC (single file component) in django

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-sfc

**fil1.vue**

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <input v-model="msg">
</template>
```

I would like to render this in my Django template.

**Previously with normal vue components I was able to do use them as follows:**

JS file:

```
Vue.component('comp1', {...})
```

django html template:

```
<comp1> </comp1>
```

#### Update 04-08-2022

I was able to get App.vue mounted on django div element with `id=app` -[My github repo](https://github.com/aseem-hegshetye/django_vue3_sfc)

- The only way this works is when I set `id=app` in `homepage.html` . Is there another way of rendering `App.vue` in django [homepage.html](https://github.com/aseem-hegshetye/django_vue3_sfc/blob/main/homepage/templates/homepage/homepage.html) ?
- Is there a way to use component `<HelloWorld>` directly in my django template ?

If someone can provide a link to a public github repo that has used SFC with django that would be helpful.

Comment: This may be feasible in the same way: https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-component This one does not work?

Comment: Can you provide a working example please?

Answer (score 1):

Following is what I know so far. There may be a better solution out there.

- Django has its own routers and template engine. Django can render html pages on certain URLs.
- Vue SFC has its own routers. In Vue3 SFC everything start from a single entrypoint file with `id=app` and from there we can route users to different pages. Everything is done in Vue. No Django needed or used.
- So using SFC with Django is not possible or is not the correct approach.
- We can use SFC for UI and DRF for APIs. This can be a good combination where DRF is completely independent of Vue SFC

##### I like Vue components and I also like Django routers and Django template engine.

Following is how I am using it currently:

- I dont use Vue SFC but I do use Vue components. I am using `Vue2.6` .
- I have templates rendered by django. They call different Vuejs components;

**component1.js**

```
   Vue.component('name-comp', {
    props: {
          
       },
       data: function () {
           return {
          
           }
       },
       watch: {
          
       },
       mounted: async function () {
          
       },
       methods: {
         
    
       },
       template: `
    
       `,
       delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
   });
```

**h1.html**

```
<name-comp></name-comp>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app1/js/component1.js'%}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use customElements and defineCustomElement in this way

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import AddListing from "./components/AddListing.vue";
import EditListing from "./components/EditListing.vue";

// Add Listing form
customElements.define('add-listing', defineCustomElement(AddListing))
customElements.define('edit-listing', defineCustomElement(EditListing))

const marketApp = createApp(App)
marketApp.mount('#app')
```

Then you will be able to use it outside of div#app by calling:

```
<add-listing />
```

or

```
<edit-listing />
```